# Many classes with the same constructors

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have many classes that are only similar in the arguments they take. Is there a way to write this more concisely/neatly? Writing a baseclass that contains the member variables would help a bit, but I'd still need to write out the constructor for each class.

```
class CommandDrawLiver {
    protected:
        int age;
        Species species;
        double r, g, b;
    public:
        CommandDrawLiver( int _age, Species _species, double _r, double _g, double _b )
          : age(_age), species(_species), r(_r), g(_g), b(_b)
          {};
};
class CommandDrawBrain {
    protected:
        int age;
        Species species;
        double r, g, b;
    public:
        CommandDrawBrain( int _age, Species _species, double _r, double _g, double _b )
          : age(_age), species(_species), r(_r), g(_g), b(_b)
          {};
};
class CommandDrawHeart {
    protected:
        int age;
        Species species;
        double r, g, b;
    public:
        CommandDrawHeart( int _age, Species _species, double _r, double _g, double _b )
          : age(_age), species(_species), r(_r), g(_g), b(_b)
          {};
};
```

Comment: Some sort of factory function template? `template <typename T> T makeCommandDraw(int, Species&, double, double, double) {//...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a compiler that supports C++11, That's what [inheriting constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement) is for... 
Check it out and use it

Here is how to apply it...

```
class Species{};

class CommandDraw {
    protected:
        int age;
        Species species;
        double r, g, b;

    public:
        CommandDraw( int _age, Species _species, double _r, double _g, double _b )
          : age(_age), species(_species), r(_r), g(_g), b(_b)
          {};
};

class CommandDrawLiver : public CommandDraw {
    public:
        using CommandDraw::CommandDraw;
};
class CommandDrawBrain : public CommandDraw {
    public:
        using CommandDraw::CommandDraw;
};
class CommandDrawHeart : public CommandDraw {
    public:
        using CommandDraw::CommandDraw;
};

int main() {
    CommandDrawLiver cd(34, Species(), 12, 45, 67);
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome. I just edited the answer to show usage, if that solves your problem, you can mark it answered :-)